# How to config devise redirection path after failed sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Because I wanna embed sign in form in the navbar, I want devise to redirect the user to root path after failed sign in. But devise always redirects to /user/sign_in. How can I change this behavior?

I'm using rails 4.1.6 with devise 3.4.0

Answer (score 3):

You can override `Devise::SessionsController` to achieve this

First, create the inherited Devise controller as follows

```
$ rails g devise:controllers user --controllers=sessions
      create  app/controllers/user/sessions_controller.rb
===============================================================================

Some setup you must do manually if you haven't yet:

  Ensure you have overridden routes for generated controllers in your route.rb.
  For example:

    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users, controllers: {
        sessions: 'sessions'
      }
    end

===============================================================================
```

You need to modify the `create` method in `app/controllers/user/sessions_controller.rb`. [Here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L15) you'll find the original `create` method provided by Devise. Line 17, `self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)`, means if authentication fails, the request will be halted and the user is redirected to the previous page which is `/user/sign_in`. Implement the `create` method in your `SessionsController` as follows

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)

  if self.resource
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  else
    # Authentication fails, redirect the user to the root page     
  end
end
```

See [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/warden/Warden/Proxy#authenticate-instance_method) to understand the difference between `warden.authenticate!` and `warden.authenticate`

Let me know if it works for you.